# How to inherit global settings class in different Android projects

Tags: android

I have several different Android projects that use a library where I've created most of the common classes. One of the classes is "commonSettingsAndFunctions" where I've defined several static strings and methods to be used. Example:

```
public class commonSettingsAndFunctions {
  public static String flurryCode = "MY_FLURRY_CODE";
  public static final int APP_VERSION = 2;
  public static final String API_URL = "http://mydomain/api.jsp"

  public static String getAPIUrl(Context context, String parameters) {
    // code
  }
}
```

However, now I've come up with a situation where I have to change some of the settings per project. For example, flurry code and app version. API_URL is always (so far) the same.

What's the best way to implement this? One option I thought of is making commonSettingsAndFunction as abstract, create  a class "commonSettingsAndFunctionsReal extends commonSettingsAndFunctions", then implement the "Real" class per project? Another possibilities?

I come from PHP world, and there I'd just have settings as a class, and do this in some "global include file":

```
$common = new commonSettingsAndFunctions();
$common->flurryCode = "ABCD";
```

Comment: Extending your settings class sounds like a good idea, but making the parent abstract probably isn't necessary.

Comment: When extending, what about the references? All other library classes reference to "commonSettingsAndFunctions" class.

Comment: As long as you don't touch the base class commonSettingsAndFunctions, all other classes will keep functioning as they were. However, on a second thought, as you declared everything static, I wonder what the behaviour would be if you extended the class and altered flurryCode within the extended class. Would commonSettingsAndFunctions.flurryCode return the altered version as well..?

Answer (score 0):

AppVersion is something that is in the AndroidManifest.xml and you can access that from code, so you don't really need your own version of it.  As fo the Flurry API key, I always put mine in my strings.xml so I can load it in when I need it.